# Make File to run on Linux/ MAC OS to compile .Java Files to an exe form

Tags: java, compiler-construction, jar, makefile, .class-file

I am a beginner in Java. I made my Java program using NetBeans. Now I have my .jar file.
But I would like to know how to write commands to compile  .Java classes to .Class and then build a jar using those .Class files.

Does any one have an idea how to create a Make file/ Script for running on Mac to run my source code by compiling it itself.

Comment: If you need an actual EXE file, look at jsmooth which can run under Linux/OS X.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`maven`](http://maven.apache.org/)  This will download dependencies, build you class files and build a jar for you.